# Persistence provider for Java that supports final fields

Tags: java, persistence

I'm very new to Java but I've been developing a habit to use final wherever possible declaring immutability which i think is a good thing. (Consider f#)

I've read that JPA does not support final fields. Hibernate, TopLink? I'm not sure about these but i prefer JPA for now.

Is that even possible theoretically - let's say through reflection - to modify final fields after creation? My guess would be... NO :)

What would be certainly possible for a persistence solution is to support constructors with parameters. At least i see no reason that would make this impossible. Mapping would be a little tricky i guess. 
This is an alternative solution.

Suggestions?

**EDIT:** I'm not familiar with the exact definition for immutable so i used it in this post intuitively. Declaring Immutability here means declaring that a field cannot be changed. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Object immutability (note the difference between an immutable object, and declaring a field final - an object is ONLY immutable if ALL fields are final, thus the object's state can't change after creation) is a very sensitive topic. I like them myself, and hibernate supports them through @Immutable.

Don't know about it's status in JPA 2, but to answer the question about final fields: you CAN change their values using reflection - but reflection is severly limited in a Java EE environment.

To enlighten the main problem: if your POJOs are immutable, then how would a persistent solution recreate the objects? Let's say you have two final int fields, and a constructor to initialize them. The persistence layer cannot have any information about their order, or their names (as field and parameter names are erased during compiling).

Koshuke posted a blog about this (in relation to JAXB supporting immutable beans), but can't find it right now.

Comment: Parameter names are available with Java 8, and with older versions you can get them using Paranamer during the build.

Answer (score 4):

This may not be exactly what you're striving for, but the immutability principle can easily be supported by non-final private fields having only a getter. The compiler in fact recognizes this and generates code which is pretty much identical to what you'd get with fields declared as final.

This will require you to be conscientious and not change your fields from within the containing class (whereas `final` would enforce that), but I think this is not a big price to pay for the flexibility you gain.

Comment: I would put this answer forward as the correct one.

Comment: It's a pity though, with final modifier it is clear that you have designed this way. Removing the setter it's not a good solution, you still can modify the state and someone in the team will eventually do it, as it's very tempting, and you can't enforce it. Frameworks (at least persistence frameworks) should support this IMHO, it is a very useful tool

Answer (score 3):

Good question. Actually it is a good idea to declare fields as final if they do not change (you get then initialization guarantees from the JMM).

The JPA Spec is clear regarding final fields:

> The entity class must not be final. 
>   No methods or *persistent instance variables* of the entity class may be final.

Hoever, not all implementations follow this rule and handle final fields:

- OpenJPA does not support final fields, i.e. they are treated as transient. 
  Upon loading the final fields of such an entity are initialized with the values as 
  defined in the parameterless constructor.
- The Hibernate implementation however supports final fields. Upon construction the final fields 
  which have been initialized in the parameterless constructor are replaced with the values stored
  in the database.

So to answer your question: Yes, there are JPA persistence providers which support final fields, 
however I recommend not using final fields in your entity classes as the behavior is not defined
(and actually differs from provider to provider). Moreover, I think it is a bad idea that a
JPA provider changes final fields after construction because visibility guarantees may be violated this way.

Answer (score 0):

Final fields can't be modified after creation by design. Doing otherwise is a very bad idea, because somebody can rely on standard behavior.

In general, persistence frameworks deal with hierarchies of "normal" objects. You have objects, that can be only created and removed, not modified. That's very odd, because when you create an entity, you create some kind of ID for it. Through this ID you connect entity to others. When you remove old entity and create another, you (in general) get an entity with another ID. So, all connections (foreign keys) are broken. Is it target behaviour?

Answer (score -2):

This is honestly a strange idea.

By making fields `final`, you tell the compiler they'll **never** change after object creation. As a consequence, it is a reasonable assumption to not persist them, since they will never change. Well, by writing this, I assume you have the java culture, but the question you ask precisely tells the contrary.

In Java, persisted obejcts are "always" assumed to be POJO (in other words, Java Beans). A Java Bean must have (to be considered as such) an empty constructor that will allow persistance frameworks and so on to construct it using its empty constructor, by indirectly calling it through Class.newInstance()/.

There are fields where non empty constructors are used (like IoC containers - Guice, Spring and Tapestry IoC), but it is out of the scope of Java Beans, which have to be considered as data objects.

Comment: What about a read-only database? BTW i'm just exploring possibilities.

Comment: Other use cases: multiple entity for one table. Or creating those entities through a factory method.

Comment: Sorry. I don't get this at all.  If what you're saying is that existing persistence frameworks only support JavaBeans, you may be right. But if you are saying that there is something intrinsic to immutable objects that make them unsuitable for persistence, I totally disagree.  One might argue that the Java language make working with immutable objects tedious, but frameworks could easily mitigate these deficiencies.

Comment: In the first paragraph of your answer, you seem to be assuming that an object is being retrieved from a database, modified, and then committed, and therefore the object needs to be modifiable in-place in order to be useful.  In many (perhaps most) cases, the persistence client is a stateless server where the update externalized (web page, whatever) and a new object is realized, on the commit call (POST,PUT). In this case I would prefer immutable objects, because it enforces referential transparency, especially if complex business validations are done prior to commit.

Comment: And even in cases where a closed process scenario where an entity is retrieved, modified, and committed. I would still favour immutable objects because, even though you cannot do an update-in-place, you can do an update-on-copy with immutable objects, and then commit the updated copy.  I'd still favour the immutable objects in this case since you may still need to pass the object to many validators, for which referential transparency would be ideal.

Comment: @dsmith First and foremost, existing persistence framework are indeed built with JavaBeans in mind. To be honest, when they were conceived (15 years ago), JavaBeans were supposed to be a good idea. Nowadays, people are jumping in the immutable functionnal bandwagon, and these concerns of creating immutable objects start to make sense.

Comment: @Riduidel this is true. Although I'm not sure how difficult it would be to retrofit existing persistence frameworks to be aware of other construction mechanisms like builders.  For example, the Jackson framework for JSON.

Comment: an event is immutable yet it makes sense to persist it.